# bash script doing back-up malfunctions when run via systemd

Tags: bash, systemd, zfs

I have bash script that takes ZFS snapshot and via piping uploads it to s3 bucket. This is the gist of it:

```
torun="zfs send -c ztank/data@$BACKUP_NAME | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iter 1000 -salt -pass pass:$BACKUP_PASS  | lz4c | $s3_command s3 cp --expected-size 188743680 - s3://instamongo.backup/$BACKUP_NAME.lz"
```

when run manually (by root) it does exactly what's expected.

when run via systemd timer no errors are thrown, small file is uploaded BUT when uncompressed & decrypted the content is empty.

when I start the service unit via systemctl again the script works fine.

the problem appears to be that only when triggered by the  timer ZFS sends empty content? BUT the problem is the timestamps in the log file show it took the usual time (3+ hours for 900G raw data) to finish the upload so this does not make sense.

here are the systemd units:

```
[Unit]
Description=backup mongo
ConditionVirtualization=!container

[Service]
User=root
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/root/s3backup.sh
```

and

```
[Unit]
Description=backup mongo once per week
ConditionVirtualization=!container

[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
AccuracySec=1h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```